# The implicit shape can't be a fractional number

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I am trying to create a label in TensorFlow.
This is [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acuZp.jpg) inside the code below.

```js
async function main(){
    const model = await mobilenet.load();
    const classifier = await knnClassifier.create();
    const buf = fs.readFileSync('./41.png');
    const decode = tfnode.node.decodeImage(buf);
    console.log(decode)
    return new Promise(async resolve => {
        const embedding = model.infer(
            decode,
            false
        );
        classifier.addExample(
            embedding,
            'rong'
        )
    })
}
```

And I got this error:

```
(node:17992) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: The implicit shape can't be a fractional number. Got 200704 / 150528
```

This is when I console.log() the decode:

```js
Tensor {
  kept: false,
  isDisposedInternal: false,
  shape: [ 475, 475, 4 ],
  dtype: 'int32',
  size: 902500,
  strides: [ 1900, 4 ],
  dataId: {},
  id: 264,
  rankType: '3',
  scopeId: 311
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem as yours just last night. I was wondering why it would not work with PNG images but JPG images work just fine. As it turned out, it has something to do the [number of channels](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60128827/14580435) used when decoding the image from buffer.

When we use the `decodeImage` function ([reference](https://js.tensorflow.org/api_node/1.2.7/#node.decodeImage)), it uses 3 channels for JPG and 4 channels for PNG. However, the model expects 3 channels. Upon decoding the image, we can explicitly tell the `decodeImage` to use 3 channels for all types of images to be decoded.

The revised code would look like this:

```js
async function main() {
    const model = await mobilenet.load();
    const classifier = await knnClassifier.create();
    const buf = fs.readFileSync('./41.png');
    const decode = tfnode.node.decodeImage(buf, 3);

    return new Promise(async resolve => {
        const embedding = model.infer(decode, false);
        classifier.addExample(embedding, 'rong');
    })
}
```

Where the `decodeImage` now accepts a second argument indicating the number of channels to be used during image decoding.